# Scroll transition style of pageViewController is not smooth

Tags: scroll, transition, uipageviewcontroller

I am working with UIpageViewController.

I have a page view controller and in this page view controller I load a tableView controller when user try to view next page.

Everything is fine except transitioning of pages. When i change the page using "Scroll" style , the transition is not smooth, but when i change the page using "page Curl" style the transition is smooth.

I am looking for the reason that why my transitions are not smooth in case of "scroll" style ? I am not sending any network request on main thread moreover i had also implemented the page view controller's delegates methods i.e. viewControllerAfterViewController , ViewControllerBeforeViewController , didFinishAnimating. Can anyone suggest the solution?

Answer (score 1):

I find the reason , actually when I load new Table view controller (TVC) in `PageViewController` , the TVC contains many UI elements that make transition slow as it take some time to load all UI elements.
On Ipod it was not smooth but on Iphone 5 and above it is smooth. Because they have faster processors than ipod.